# ngx_pagespeed behind Varnish, how specify multiple (or correct) DownstreamCachePurgeLocationPrefix?

Tags: nginx, varnish, mod-pagespeed

We use Google PageSpeed module with Nginx behind Varnish.

Pagespeed only delivers partially optimized page on first hit and we use this config to make Pagespeed send purge requests to Varnish so that Varnish will clear that page once Pagespeed does indeed have a fully optimized version:

```
pagespeed DownstreamCachePurgeLocationPrefix http://10.128.1.1:6081;
pagespeed DownstreamCachePurgeMethod PURGE;
pagespeed DownstreamCacheRewrittenPercentageThreshold 95;
```

Problem is we have multiple Varnish sitting in front of multiple pagespeed receptors and varnish directs traffic in round robin.

So if app-05 for example gets the traffic, there's no telling which varnish proxy cached that page. What nginx variable can I use to tell pagespeed what varnish server cached the first partially optimized page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send purge request back to correct varnish server.
On Varnish side I put in vcl_recv:

```
set req.http.X-Forwarded-From = server.ip;
```

And then on Nginx I put:

```
pagespeed DownstreamCachePurgeLocationPrefix http://$http_x_forwarded_from:6081;
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't seem to be.

I know the variable is getting populated with Varnish ip in Nginx (because I echoed it via a 200 response) but for whatever reason pagespeed doesn't seem to want to accept the ip address from this variable.

Comment: I tried putting this at server {} level in nginx conf `pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
pagespeed ProcessScriptVariables on;` but it didn't allow pagespeed to process nginx varaibles. apparently this setting only makes nginx variables available to the loadfromfile directive. :( maybe this is not possible.

Comment: Update: I got in touch with the developers and they said they would add this feature. https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/903 So monitor that and update when released. Until then the only solution we can think of is to not use round-robin.